# Images won't show up in javascript slideshow google SameSite error

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, slideshow

[image]in short i'm doing an E-commerce website, so i did the slideshow (carousel) and it works pretty fine on a separated file or another project but when i run it in the E-commerce site that i'm working on everything like javascript and arrows and everything works fine but **images** just show up for like **half a second** and then images **disappears**

Note: the bootstrap ready to use slideshow (carousel) works well so maybe something is missing in my css.

The **errors** that shows up in the **console** dev tools are :

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://www.google.com/ was set without the 
`SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests 
if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://google.com/ was set without the `SameSite` 
attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are 
set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under 
Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.


Google Maps JavaScript API warning: RetiredVersion https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#retired-version
yz.o @ util.js:233
```

**Files html, Javascript and css**

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://web-assets-mk.s3.amazonaws.com/modules/homeslider/images/d51c6348ab0d1da1cd0363937a466c885a6ecd4b_EID-2020-SITE-mardi.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://web-assets-mk.s3.amazonaws.com/modules/homeslider/images/34a20f7ca4995e17158066883e899d22469e447c_moussem--collection-montre-femmes-siteweb.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="https://web-assets-mk.s3.amazonaws.com/modules/homeslider/images/28db48d914a82dd727adf1ba5eea0bb93c7368cf_Huawei-nova-7i-site.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

[image: at first it show up just fine like that]

[image: then after like half a second or a second it disappears]

[image: the error that shows up in console]

Comment: I ran your code snippet and it works perfectly fine, so in sum your code is ok, the problem must be with the e-commerce site you're working on. Can you show how things go wrong?

Comment: @MansouriAla its the proble of same-site cookie:

Comment: please have a look into this https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/samesite-cookie-changes-in-february.html

Comment: if the server-side code is under your control then you have to set some parameters in your response.

Comment: If you want to recreate this issue again then clean the cache of the browser and reload, the error will appear again

Comment: yet the problem that i have only these three files with some more css and html but the problem i think is with the css something is missing out there maybe

Comment: @MansouriAla Can you show the live version website? There must be some CSS overriding or JavaScript conflicting that causes the problem.

Comment: what you mean by live the source code? because it's not hosted yet if that what you mean. i'm still working on it